# Flask-cookiecutter how to change the default ip and port in dev

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server, cookiecutter

I am trying to use flask-cookiecutter, https://github.com/konstantint/cookiecutter-flask , to build a website/learn flask and webdev.  I have the dev env setup on a mac and I want to run it from a Centos VM on my mac.  My problem is how do I set the default ip and port to something other than http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in a non-horrific manner(patching flask source code)?

Comment: Do you want to run flask in another port ?

Comment: I want it to run on a different IP and port

Comment: Tried this `flask run -h 127.4.5.4 -p 5242`

Comment: Flask Cookiecutter says use 'npm start', I would like to have it work with 'npm start'

Comment: Where in the documentation it says about `npm start` ?

Comment: README.rst is where it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149208/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-ms4720).

Answer (score 0):

To change flask run defaults edit package.json node file

add **-- -h 192.168.33.15** to the 'npm run flask-server ' string

Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script